# No route registered for static file in Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, cypress

I have a Azure App Service that runs a ReactJS application. In the release pipeline I extract a zip file that contains my Cypress test results.

When I navigate to my Kudu console I can find the correct folder and files in my `PS D:\home\site\wwwroot\e2e\mochawesome-report>` folder. But when I navigate to 
a video:

https://exampleUrl/e2e/mochawesome-report/video/onboarding.spec.js.mp4

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

But when I navigate to: `https://exampleUrl.azurewebsites.net/e2e/mochawesome-report/screenshot/customer-card.spec.js/Customer card action tab -- can click on the account tab (failed).png`

I can view the image.

Is there some configuration needed to view static files?

**##EDIT##**

Added my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm pretty sure I found this somewhere on the web.

Something else I noticed. I can now open a .html and .css, .js and .png files but no .json, .woff, .woff2 and mp4.

Comment: Where does your `web.config` come from? Did you create it yourself or let the pipeline create it?

Comment: @ghostbbbmt I've updated my question with the web.config information

Comment: I tested your `web.config` and created my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define file extensions to your web app.

Add these lines to your `web.config`, below your `</rewrite>`, then restart your Web App:

```
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />                   
    </staticContent>
```

To add other extensions (like `json`):

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/plain" /
```

The result would be:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />                   
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/plain" /        
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Yea thanks. I was lazy haha. I've pushed the code. If it works I'll upvote :)

Comment: You can edit your `web.config` directly on your Kudo console and restart your Web App. Hope it works :D